# shortcut to validate if an array exists and contains no values

Tags: php, arrays

What is a shortcut to validate if an array exists and contains no values?

for some reason, this looks weird

```
$warning = array();

if (isset($warning) && empty($warning)) {
   //go on...
} else {
  //either the array doesn't exist or it exist but contains values...
}
```

the array needs to exist and must contain no values

Comment: `if ($warning) {
   ...
}` ?

Comment: or just `if empty($warning)`, `empty` will react if the variable if undefined.

Comment: @budwiser the array must exist before continuing with the code... this will either throw an error or go on... wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the shortest you will be able to get it if you do not know whether or not the variable is defined.

If you always go about defining the array `($warning = array())`, you could skip the `isset` step.

Comment: i guess there is no shorcut after all... i'll have to use both isset and empty to make sure that the array exist and contains no values...

Comment: I +1'd you Seth, because after all it turned out that you were right ;)

Comment: @budwiser Thank you :) and thanks for teaching me I was wrong about empty!

Comment: Thank YOU for teaching me that I once again didn't understand the whole question :D

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($warning) {
   ...
}
```

Would not that work? Of course before checking this you are probably assigning something to it.

**Addendum:**

This code outputs `no`, without even having the array initialized.

```
if ($warning) echo "yes";
else echo "no";
```

Comment: This should work, but prints a notice if the variable is not initialized - @Marko is that counts?

Comment: @pozs i dont want the code to start throwing notices... i just want to make sure that the array exist and has no values.

Comment: are not you assigning something to your array before checking it?

Comment: @Marco I know, but if the variable is always initialized (f.ex. it is a parameter in a function, etc. - like in your example) it won't throw anything. So it depends on the context.

Answer (score -1):

First, check if the array object itself is allocated, then the individual indexes for allocation.